# SQL Server - weird CASE bahavior - Simple Case vs Searched Case

Tags: sql-server, case

I recently ran into this pickle with the `CASE-THEN-ELSE` statement in SQL Server (2014 if it matters), to be more accurate, **"the Simple" vs "the Searched"** CASE expression. Until now, I thought that the only difference between these 2 is simply the format and/or the habit in writing both ways of the case expression but I guess I was completely wrong :)

[MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

> The CASE expression has two formats:
>
> The simple CASE expression
>   compares an expression to a set of simple expressions to determine the
>   result.
>
> The searched CASE expression evaluates a set of Boolean
>   expressions to determine the result.

Here is the example:

```
set nocount on
declare @test nvarchar(50) = null

select 
    @test as [The NULL Value], 
    case 
       when @test is null 
          then null 
          else 'Not Null???' 
    end as [As Expected],
    case @test 
       when null 
          then null 
          else 'Not Null???' 
    end as [The Pickle]
```

And the result is:

```
The NULL Value                                     As Expected The Pickle
-------------------------------------------------- ----------- -----------
NULL                                               NULL        Not Null???
```

Could someone provide a link to a MSDN documentation where this is explained, perhaps in a more detailed manner? :)

P.S.: I bet a lot of you folks were certain that both results would yield the same output :D

Comment: Do try this with `set ansi_nulls off` on top and watch what happens. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It's not weird at all ...

The "shortcut" way of

```
 case @test 
       when null 
          then null 
          else 'Not Null???' 
    end as [The Pickle]
```

evaluates the variable/column (here: `@test`) against the values in the `WHEN` clauses (`when null`) with the regular equality operator - and comparing `NULL` using the standard equality operator (`@test = null`) is **always** undefined/NULL itself (standard SQL behavior), so it's **not** true

Therefore you are getting this result - `Not Null???` - for your column `The Pickle`

If you want to check for `NULL`, you **must** use `IS NULL` like in your first example...

Comment: Well said. Changing `ansi_nulls` to off does the trick though.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t int =1

--simple case
select 
case @t 
when 1 then 1 else null end
```

The above query is expanded to below form..

```
select 
case when @t=1 then 1 else null end
```

so a query with null will expand to below

```
declare @t int=null
select case @t
when null then null else 'notnull' end
```

is expanded to

```
select case when @t=null then null else 'notnull' end
```

which obviously evaluates to not null..

So in summary only in null case you will not get results you are expecting,try below to see

```
declare @t int=null
declare @t1 int =1

select 
case when @t is null then null else 'notnull' end as 'Searchedcase',
case @t when null then null else 'notnull' end as'simple case',
case when @t1 =1 then 1 else  null end as 'Searchedcase for value',
case @t1 when 1 then 1 else null end as'simple case for value'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. See discussion of  [NULL and UNKNOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204037.aspx) from Transact-SQL reference to get a handle on why '=' doesn't work for NULL.
2. Simple CASE must be implicitly using '=', rather than IS NULL.  So to make IS NULL explicit, use a Searched CASE expression.
3. Maybe Microsoft will add some functionality to the simple CASE expression to if NULL is encountered, then operator 'IS' is used?